# Problems publishing app android

Tags: android, google-play

I have a "little" app on market, and uploaded a new version of it, but when I upload the apk this message appears:

***This setting can not be published for the following reasons:
The version 2 is not available on any device configuration: every device that can receive  version 2 receives version 3.***

and the state of the 3rd version is "draft in final phase"

How can i fix it?

[image]

I put the Manifest if can be helpfull

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shudy.lightson"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.shudy.lightson.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
            <meta-data android:value="aXXXXXXXXXXX2" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Deactivate your latest version and then upload your new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all good. This is how Google Play works. It's just saying that the new version will work for all the devices that are support by older versions. So the old version is obsolete and should be deactivated.

Deactivate the old version and all will be fine.